# Getting "int" accepted as an instance of my Django model

Tags: python, django

I'm writing a decorator to allow my functions to accept either an instance of one of my Django models or its primary key, and the function itself will always receive an instance regardless of which was passed in. While testing it, I'm getting a weird error that sometimes, an integer (the usual type for the primary key) is being considered a valid instance of my model. For example:

```
log.debug((value, type(value), model, isinstance(value, model)))
# Outputs: (1, <class 'int'>, <class 'myapp.models.MyModel'>, True)
```

This behavior is consistent within my decorator function, but I can't replicate it from a bare Django shell; I've tried using 1, valid primary keys for `MyModel`, and other values, and it always returns `False` properly. This check also works properly in some other test cases using other models, returning `False` when a key is passed in rather than an object instance.

`MyModel` does have a couple of extra inheritances, in particular it overrides `__str__` and `__repr__`, and inherits from `natural_keys.NaturalKeyModel`, which doesn't override anything that seems relevant to this issue. Otherwise, it's just a typical Django model, no special definition of `__eq__` or anything like that.

Any ideas why my `isinstance` check is behaving this way? For completeness, my entire decorator is below.

```
def with_obj(name, model,
             required=True, key_name='pk', select_for_update=False, select_related=tuple(), prefetch_related=tuple(),
             _default=None):
    """Retrieves an object of the given model, given either an instance of that model or a primary key.

    Args:
        name (str): The argument name to find and modify
        model (models.Model): The model type to expect or retrieve
        required (bool): If False and no value is provided for this argument, None will be passed. If True, an exception will be thrown if not value is provided. True by default.
        key_name (str): The name of the key field on the model to use if looking up an instance from a primitive value. "pk" by default.
        select_for_update (bool): Whether or not to mark this object as being selected for updating. If True, this also wraps the function call in an ``atomic`` block. An object selected for updating cannot be fetched by another process (using a database lock) until this function returns.
        select_related (tuple(str)): An optional tuple of fields to be pre-fetched using ``select_related``.
        prefetch_related (tuple(str)): An optional tuple of many-to-* fields to be pre-fetched using ``prefetch_related``.

    Returns:
        ((function) -> function): A decorator that guarantees that an argument will be provided to the wrapped function as defined here.
    """
    import inspect
    import functools

    _maybe_atomic = atomic if select_for_update else lambda x: x

    def _decorator(f):
        @functools.wraps(f)
        @_maybe_atomic
        def _inner(*args, **kwargs):
            # Get whatever was passed for _name_
            signature = inspect.signature(f).bind(*args, **kwargs)
            signature.apply_defaults()
            value = signature.arguments[name]

            # Replace that value with the corresponding instance from _model_
            # Note, this WILL cause a re-fetch even if the object was already passed in
            # This is intentional behavior to prevent objects from being cached in the tasks queue and saved with old
            #  values
            log.debug((value, type(value), model, isinstance(value, model)))  # <-- This prints the issue
            value = model.objects.filter(**{key_name: getattr(value, key_name) if isinstance(value, model) else value})  # <-- This line fails, due to retrieving "pk" from type "int"
            if select_for_update:
                value = value.select_for_update()
            if select_related:
                value = value.select_related(*select_related)
            if prefetch_related:
                value = value.prefetch_related(*prefetch_related)

            if required and _default is None:
                # This will throw an exception if no object is found, so only call if we want to fail in that case
                value = value.get()
            else:
                value = value.first()

            if value is None and _default is not None:
                value = _default()

            # Modify the call signature to use this new value
            signature.arguments[name] = value
            return f(*signature.args, **signature.kwargs)

        return _inner

    return _decorator
```

EDIT: I tried checking against `MyModel.__instancecheck__(value)` directly, and this always returns the correct, expected value, in this case `False`. Particularly:

```
log.debug((value, type(value), model, isinstance(value, model), model.__instancecheck__(value)))
# Outputs: (1, <class 'int'>, <class 'myapp.models.MyModel'>, True, False)
```

What can cause `isinstance` to return different results than `__instancecheck__`?

Comment: I'm unable to duplicate this when testing locally. Can you include a python repl example with some values that cause this error?

Comment: I'm unable to replicate it outside of one test case too... I'll post an edit if I can figure out what causes the check to behave different in that one context.

Comment: Geez... I feel like an idiot. Will post an answer clearing this up. Thanks for the effort, @damon

Answer (score 1):

And here's where I admit what an idiot I am:

```
from unittest.mock import patch

# ...

with patch('my_module.isinstance') as _isinstance:
    _isinstance.return_value = True
    # Call offending code
```

So I wasn't calling the actual `isinstance` builtin function, I was calling my own mocked version of it that always returned `True`.